# Blocking all YouTube videos, including those embedded in websites

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, youtube

I'm not just talking about auto buffering, nor related videos.

I would like to not play any YouTube videos embedded in any websites.

Is that possible with Firefox (first priority), or IE and/or Chrome (second priority?)

Answer (score 4):

I see 3 ways.

**1) With a browser extension**:

You can use an adblocker (like uBlock Origin, uMatrix, ScriptSafe) to block Youtube requests. You can stop these requests by default on all websites. For my example, go to [this website](https://kaiakater.com/video).

Here, the embedded Youtube videos will display on:

[image]

Then here, the embedded Youtube videos will do not display on:

[image]

**2) With the "hosts" file**:

Edit your [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file with a text editor (like Atom, Sublime Text, Vim, Notepad++...) and put this long list of URLs:

```
0.0.0.0 youtu.be
0.0.0.0 youtube.com
0.0.0.0 www.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 uk.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 de.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 tr.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 jp.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 au.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 ca.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 fr.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 ru.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 help.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 m.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 img.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 gdata.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v1.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v2.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v3.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v4.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v5.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v6.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v7.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v8.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v9.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v10.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v11.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v12.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v13.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v14.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v15.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v16.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v17.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v18.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v19.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v20.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v21.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v22.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v23.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v24.sjc.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 sjc-v25.sjc.youtube.com
```

**3) With a script (or a browser extension)**:

It stops Youtube video played in an iframe. The best method should be to remove this iframe if it contains an URL from Youtube.
A quick help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164942/stop-embedded-youtube-iframe
Sorry, I did not find a good script but I know it is possible. The script must work asyncronysly (because the Youtube HTML requests are asynchronous).

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. Select the `hosts` file (not the calendar). Right click and open it with notepad, notepad++, or another basic text editor. At the bottom add the following entry, and save the file:

> 0.0.0.0 youtube.com

You may need to open the file as an administrator in order to save it. However, this will block all connections to youtube from your computer.